# Performing a Bulk insert into two tables

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

So I am have some statistical studies that I would like to import into a MySQL databases. The studies have numerous variables, each is used to create a column in my database. I have a CSV file of all the data in my studies that I would like to import into my database as well.

Some of the studies have greater than 1000 variables in them. This means there will be more than 1000 columns in my table, which I know is the limit in MySql. Because of this I have to create multiple tables for my study and combine them using a view to see all the variables at once.

Does this mean that I will have to have multiple CSV files as well (one for each 1000 column table) or is there some way to perform a bulk insert from a CSV file into two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly need multiple tables. I would write a script to read the csv files.and them write the data to the database.

However, before just dumping the data, I would look for opportunities to normalize/rationalize the dataset. You may discover that normalisation may actually help in your analysis.